# Ubuntu tutorial: The Linux command line for beginner

Tags: command-line

Going through the tutorial and everything going as should until the cat command.  I combined echo and redirect for test_1.txt, test_2.txt, and test_3.txt like instructed but when I went to the next step and tried the cat command, I get the following:

```
jojo@Joanne-Laptop:/tmp/tutorial$ cat test_1.txt test_2.txt test_3.txt  
cat: test_1.txt: No such file or directory
cat: test_2.txt: No such file or directory
cat: test_3.txt: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to solve on my own by trying the following commands in shell:

first tried:

```
chmod u+rw text_1.txt
namei -lx
```

it looks like i dont have all the permissions but idk

OUTPUT:

```
f: output.txt
-rw-rw-r-- jojo jojo output.txt

f: text_1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- jojo jojo text_1.txt

f: text_2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- jojo jojo text_2.txt

f: text_3.txt
-rw-rw-r-- jojo jojo text_3.txt
```

next tried:

```
hash
hash -r
```

didnt change anything

will mention when i use the ls command all the files are shown

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to result from a simple typographical error

Answer (score 3):

The files you have are named `text_1.txt`, and so on, while you're looking for `test_1.txt`, and so on.

```
TEST vs TEXT
  ^       ^
```

```
$ cat text_1.txt text_2.txt text_3.txt
```